# Upgrade my dockerfile from java:8-jre to java 11?

Tags: java, docker

I currently have this dockerfile that I use for a small spring boot web application:

```
FROM java:8-jre
COPY ["target/backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "/backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
CMD ["java", "-jar", "backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I would like to update it to java 11. So I went to docker hub and found:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/11.0-jre/images/sha256-6e0b724fd42e5413fd2b3835a559ccc6c6fe621b8adb4a9ba0fa0bcfa1de55bb

and updated my dockerfile to:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-jre
COPY ["target/backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "/backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
CMD ["java", "-jar", "backend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and it looks like it builds and runs fine. But is that the best base image to use? I have read that most people recommend *alpine* (smaller) versions but I don't seem to find that on docker hub:

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=11-alpine

I did find:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jre/alpine/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full

but there is no info on how to use it - e.g. what the correct name in the FROM should be. Unless its not available as a docker image and I need to build it myself?

Comment: The Alpine Linux distribution has some compatibility issues with various pieces of software, including Java newer than 8; there is no Java 11 image based on Alpine.  I wouldn't worry about the space cost of a Debian-based image vs. an Alpine-based image in most cases.

Comment: what most people don't get is that you _can't_ run `java` from a pure alpine distro.